# ¿Como puedo introducir en la memoria del programa los datos de un diccionario que ya he guardado en un fichero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, diccionarios

Soy nuevo en python y tengo un ejercicio que me pide leer de un texto plano un diccionario y los datos implementarlos en memoria, el texto ya lo tengo guardado sería el siguiente

```
{
  '55555555L': {
    'nombre': 'Samuel',
    'dirección': 'a',
    'teléfono': '23',
    'email': '1234@gmail.com',
    'honorario': True,
    'cuota': []
  },
  '44444444B': {
    'nombre': 'Nestor',
    'dirección': 'b',
    'teléfono': '45',
    'email': '5678@gmail.com',
    'honorario': True,
    'cuota': []
  }
}
```

Entonces esto debe leerlo el programa y luego agregarlo en la base de modo que cuando muestre los socios agregados con la opción 3 o 4 del programa que mostraré, los nuevos socios se muestren.

En caso de necesitar también el script con las funciones asociadas al modo 8 y 9 las entregaré sin problema.

El caso también es que no puedo usar módulos como json, etc ya que los profesores hacen hincapié en utilizar lo que ya sabemos.

Como pueden observar con el único que tengo problemas es con la opción 7 ya que he intentado diversas formas pero no he logrado ninguna que lea el fichero y pase los datos a los diccionarios socio y socios y que por lo tanto con las opciones 3 y 4 se muestren los socios agragados tras haber cargado el texto plano o fichero.

Muchas gracias de antemano y perdonen las molestias.

Agradecería que puedan explicarme de una manera sencilla como hacerlo ya que he visto varias preguntas y las respuestas y no entiendo la mayoría.
el programa entero es el siguiente:

````
socios = {}     # Diccionario de BD de socios indexado por NIF

opción = '1'    # Opción inicialmente a 1 para entrar en el bucle
while opción != '0':
    # Visualización del menú
    print()
    print('MENÚ PARA GESTIÓN DE CLUB <Casino De Villanueva>')
    print('  0) Salir del menú')
    print('  1) Añadir socio')
    print('  2) Eliminar socio')
    print('  3) Mostrar socio')
    print('  4) Listar socios')
    print('  5) Listar socios honorarios')
    print('  6) Guardar base de datos a fichero')
    print('  7) Leer base de datos')
    print('  8) Incrementar en las cuotas pendientes de pago a todos los socios una cuota de una cantidad dada')
    print('  9) Pago de cuotas pendientes')
    print()
    opción = input('Opción: ')

    # Selección de opciones
    if opción == '1':
        print('Añadir nuevo socio. Introduce:')
        nif = input('  NIF del socio: ')
        nombre = input('  Nombre del socio: ')
        dirección = input('  Dirección del socio: ')
        teléfono = input('  Teléfono del socio: ')
        email = input('  Correo electrónico del socio: ')
        vip = input('  ¿Es un socio honorario (S/N)?: ')
        cuota = []
        socio = {'nombre':nombre, 'dirección':dirección, 'teléfono':teléfono,
                 'email':email, 'honorario':vip=='S', 'cuota':cuota}
        socios[nif] = socio
       

    elif opción == '2':
        print('Eliminar socio')
        nif = input('Introduce NIF del socio a eliminar: ')
        if nif in socios:
            del socios[nif]
            print('Socio', nif, 'eliminado')
        else:
            print('No existe el socio con el NIF', nif)

    elif opción == '3':
        print('Mostrar datos socio')
        nif = input('Introduce NIF del socio a mostrar: ')
        if nif in socios:
            print('NIF:', nif)
            for key, value in socios[nif].items():
                print(key.title() + ':', value)
        else:
            print('No existe el socio con el nif', nif)

    elif opción == '4':
        print('Listado de socios')
        for key, value in socios.items():
            print(key, value['nombre'])

    elif opción == '5':
        print('Listado de socios honorarios')
        for key, value in socios.items():
            if value['honorario']:
                print(key, value['nombre'])
   
    elif opción == '6':
        str1=str(socios)
        filename=input('Inserte el fichero para guardar la base de datos: ')
        f=open(filename, 'w')
        f.write(str1)
        f.close()
        print('Base de datos guardada')

    elif opción == '7':
        filename=input('Introduzca la base de datos: ') 
        h=open(filename, 'r')
        


    elif opción == '8':
        gest_socios.cuotas_pendientes(cuota, socios)

    elif opción == '9':
        gest_socios.pago_cuotas(cuota, socios)

    elif opción != '0':   # Se detecta si la opción no es válida
        print('Número de opción incorrecta')

# Despedida
print('Gracias por usar el programa')```
````

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que debes guardar en el fichero simplemente la conversión a cadena del diccionario? ¿O quizás puedes usar otros formatos binarios, como `pickle`? ¿O puedes inventar tu propio formato de texto, por ejemplo un CSV en el que cada línea sea un usuario y sus diferentes datos aparezcan separados por punto y coma? Lo pregunto porque, de estas tres opciones, la de volcar el diccionario como cadena es la que más complejo hace volver a leerlo (salvo que uses `eval()`, que se considera inseguro)

Comment: Al final use el modulo pickle como tu dices abulafia, esto hizo mucho más fácil la conversión, muchas gracias por la ayuda.